# DOM initMouseEvent clientX, clientY

Tags: javascript, events, dom

how can simulate an onclick event on a DIV passing only X,Y coordinates???

If I try to make that obviously the dispatchEvent function wants the
object on which the event will be raised...but then what is the meaning
of passing in event creation the coordinates????

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The clientX and clientY parameters are the position **relative to the element handling the event**, so you need to know what element the click event is going to.

If you want to simulate a click to an unknown element based on window coordinates, you will need to find the element at that position. In IE and Firefox 3, you can use `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)`. I don't know of any way in other browsers, except looping through the elements in the page, looking at their position/size to determine what's at the coordinates.

Your code would look kind of like this:

```
function simulateClick(x, y) {
    var el = getElementFromPoint(x, y);

    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
        1, 0, 0,
        calculateClientX(el, x), calculateClientY(el, y),
        false, false, false, false, 0, null);

    el.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

`getElementFromPoint` would use either `document.elementFromPoint` or iterate over all the elements. `calculateClientX/Y` would calculate the click coordinates relative to the element.

Comment: `initMouseEvent` is deprecated, we can just use `var evt = new MouseEvent('click', ...`  now. [See MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent)